# deselectRowAtIndexPath issue

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have just started working with tableViews, and I have 5 cells in a tableview in a viewController embedded in a navigationController. When a cell is pressed another view is pushed in. My problem is that the cell I press is selected but the selection doesn't go away. I have tried with this code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

NewViewController *newViewController = [[NewViewController alloc] init];

newViewController.theTitle = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].textLabel.text;

[self.navigationController pushViewController: newViewController animated:YES];

}
```

The tableView is initialized in the viewDidLoad method. 
Still when I click a cell the new viewController is pushed in but the cell stays selected. What might be the issue here?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You've put your code in the didDeselectRowAtIndexPath - put it in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath.  This is an easy mistake to make since didDeselect comes up in code completion before didSelect.

Comment: Ouch... that one took me 30 minutes, thanks for solving it :-)

Comment: @Pieter Well, it's not like brain surgery, but it's usually the little things that can cause the most grief - glad I could help!

Answer (score 3):

**Summary** :

- You have tableview that is in a ViewController that is in a NavigationController
- Use touch a cell
- A new ViewController is push on the NavigationController Stack
- User hit back and goes back to the screen where you have a tableView

That is what I understand from your question.
At this moment the cell in your tableView should still be selected in order for the user to have a reminder of the last action he as done, but you also want it to get unselected animated at the point ( the mail application is a good example of this behaviour).

So *the best place to deselect the cell in your tableView is in* `- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` method of the UIViewController that have the tableview inside it's view. By doing so you will let the user a chance to see the selection before it gently fade away like in mail.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:animated];
}
```

You can pass `nil` as argument of `deselectRowAtIndexPath`, tableView handles it gracefully.

Answer (score 2):

Did you also implement `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`? This method is called every time you tap a cell. So you should put your code there.

The method you are using, `tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:` is called whenever a cell is selected and you are tapping a different cell.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that you use wrong method. Change `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` to `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.